# How to check which XP theme is enabled

Tags: python, c, windows, winapi, windows-themes

I have a wxPython which works perfectly on window xp theme but on switching to 'classic theme'  rich text cntrl comes up without border. I can enable border for classic theme but for that

Q1. I need to know if classic theme is enabled.

Q2.I am also not sure how many different theme could be there which may break my app appearance. so what could be the best way to go around it?

Q3. Can I enforce a theme for given application? e.g. from python I can load any windows DLL and call functions, but is there any such way?

Edit: in my case ctypes.windll.UxTheme.IsThemeActive() worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic theming is more of a non theme.
You check for classic theming by calling [IsAppThemed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759809(VS.85).aspx)() in UxTheme.dll

There should therefore be little reason to worry about different themes.

Lastly, the only choice applications get is whether to try and support theming or not - by including a manifest specifying that the new common controls are to be used. Apps that don't include the manifest will never be themed. Apps that do, will be themed as per the users preferences.

Comment: In what context?
You want to force a theme on an app thats unthemed?
You want to force a theme on an app when the user has disabled themeing?
You want to force theme B on the app when the system is configured to use theme A?
In the first case, you would need to create a manifest for the app. In the next two cases, its not possible (with documented APIs).

Comment: isAppThemed returns 0 always in my case, but IsThemeActive() seems to work